# Special characters such as PI, or subscripts on the xml of Android

Tags: android

I am coding a maths app and I want to show special characters such as PI, E, or subscripts and all those things.
I want to show them on the xml file of the layout.
How can I do it?
Thank you guys for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters in a string resource are unicode.  You can include special characters using the \unnnn notation.

There are many places to look up the unicode values on the web.  Google found this one for me:
  http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Unicode value for the symbol, preceded by `\u`. For example, the *pi* character is `"\u03C0"`

Answer (score 2):

This site: http://www.dionysia.org/html/entities/symbols.html has list of elements which can be used in xml. Just watch the second element. For example:

```
square = &#8730
```

THen you need to conver it. For example:

```
String symbol = Html.fromHtml(square);
```

Alternative link is here: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/12/how-to-put-some-special-math-symbols-in-textview-editview-or-other-android-ui-element