# How to make it that users can enter pi in android studio?

Tags: java, android

1-I have an EditText and I want that users can be able to enter the Pi constant. 3.14. How could I do it? I also want to restrict them from entering and character other than pi and digits and the fraction /. How could I proceed?

2-And also if this is possible I want the answer to pi on a fraction. Example π/3 or π/4 ect. I did a method to convert from degree to radiant but I want answers with fractions.How to do this?

Comment: this might br hrlp you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058728/special-characters-such-as-pi-or-subscripts-on-the-xml-of-android

Comment: Sounds like someone is looking for help on a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add this line with your EditText tag.

```
android:digits="π/0123456789"
```

Your EditText tag should look like:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:digits="π/0123456789"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This will allow user to type only π/0123456789 in your edit text box.

2) Read the value from Edittext box as string and process the string and seperate it as character array in java. If character contain / split the string into 2 strings and divide it.